# Re-initialize angular form with dynamically generated input fields

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with a dropdown. Depending on the value of this dropdown i compile a custom directive into the form. This directive contains form inputs. When i change the dropdown value, the compiled directive gets removed and the new compiled directive will be added. so far that works fine.
I also have a form validation for the whole form. The problem is when i "switch the directive" it also validates the input fields of the old directive.
This is because $scope.form (my form) is keeping those field even tough they are not on the view anymore.

My question, is there a way to re-initialize the form on the scope so that only the form inputs shown on the view are in my angular form?

[print of $scope form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTIDu.png)

The red one are no longer on the form but still in my form object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer using ng-include.
Make your select items like

```
[{caption: 'foo', templateUrl: '/foo.html'}, {caption: 'bar', templateUrl: '/bar.html'}]
```

Where templateUrl points to desired partial view with your inputs.
Bind selected item's template url to ng-include. It will keep required partial on the page and remove your old inputs and you won't have problems with validation.

Comment: thanks. your comment made me refactoring the whole part. the problem was indeed related to the compilation of directive on the fly. with ng switch its working as expected.